# Cut multiple parts from a video and merge them together

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to cut specific parts out from a video and then merge all those parts into a single video file using nodejs and ffmpeg.

Here's my code and currently I can cut only one part out of the video from `.setStartTime` to `.setDuration` and that part is being saved.

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

var command = ffmpeg()
  .input('./videos/placeholder-video.mp4')
  .setStartTime('00:00:03')
  .setDuration('02')
  .output('./videos/test.mp4')

  .on('start', function(commandLine) {
    console.log('Started: ' + commandLine);
  })

  .on('end', function(err) {   
    if(!err)
    {
      console.log('conversion Done');
    }                 
  })

  .on('error', function(err){
    console.log('error: ', +err);
  }).run();
```

How do I cut out multiple parts out from the video and merge them in a single video file. I know about `.mergeToFile` method but how do I use it after cutting different parts from my video.

I tried using `.setStartTime` and `.setDuration` twice like below but the first one's are being ignored.

```
.input('./videos/placeholder-video.mp4')
.setStartTime('00:00:03')
.setDuration('02')
.setStartTime('00:00:15')
.setDuration('05')
.output('./videos/test.mp4')
```

Answer (score 1):

**PLEASE READ UPDATE**

Could not test it yet, but try following:
Set the input video two times, like this:

```
.input('./videos/placeholder-video.mp4')
.setStartTime('00:00:03')
.setDuration('02')
.input('./videos/placeholder-video.mp4')
.setStartTime('00:00:15')
.setDuration('05')
```

Then you can merge the multiple inputs with `.mergeToFile`.

---

**UPDATE**

My answer cannot work due to restriction of `.setDuration`. It is an output option, so it defines how long transcoding to the output file is done: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg
It is not used to define the length/duration of the input.

Another option would be `.loop`, but apparently it is not supported for this purpose: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/repeat-loop-input-video-with-ffmpeg/12906#12906

If you really want to use nodejs, you need multiple commands

- cut the input video to temporary files, one for each cut
- merge the temporary files to one output file

Something like this:

```
var command1 = ffmpeg()
  .input('./small.mp4')
  .seekInput('00:00:02')
  .withDuration(1)
  .output('./temp1.mp4')
  .run();

var command2 = ffmpeg()
  .input('./small.mp4')
  .seekInput('00:00:01')
  .withDuration(3)
  .output('./temp2.mp4')
  .run();

var command2 = ffmpeg()
  .input('./temp1.mp4')
  .input('./temp2.mp4')
  .mergeToFile('./merge.mp4', './temp');
```

**Big problem:** your nodejs script will not start if temporary files are not present.
So it would be much more easier to use a bash or batch script.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am getting two files now after giving `.output` and `.input` two times but they are not edited as expected. `test1.mp4` should be **3sec** but it it **6sec** which should be `test2.mp4` and `test2.mp4` is **2sec** less than the original video.

Comment: You're right, my answer can't work, even when used correctly ;) My idea was to use `.input` two times, but **not** use output. Instead only use `.mergeToFile`, even without `.run`. But as I said, it is not working because of `.setDuration`, which is an output option, not for input (https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg). And the option you need `.loop` is unknown by ffmpeg or hard to use or needs reencoding (https://video.stackexchange.com/a/12906). **My advise**: Write a bash script and call ffmpeg 3 times: cut the video 2 times to desired lengths into temp files and merge them.

Comment: You are right, my node app crashes since it cannot find those 2 temp files when the script runs, however when I put the third command in `setTimeout` and wait for those temp files to generate then it works and merges them. And also I don't know how to write a bash script and my requirement is actually to cut parts from a video and merge them through my web app in browser. How will my bash script work then. Anyways thank you so much for this answer.

Comment: Glad to here you have now a working solution  If you have a web app, a shell script would be hard to use and a bad idea. Nodejs would also be my preferred way! So nice to have a working example now.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would solve it:

```
(async function() {
  const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
  
  function ffmpegPromise(fn) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      fn.on('error', (e) => rej(e))
        .on('end', () => res('finished!'))
        .run()
    })
  }

  const file1 = ffmpeg().input('./videos/placeholder-video.mp4')
  .setStartTime('00:00:03')
  .setDuration(2)
  .output('./videos/test1.mp4')
  
  const file2 = ffmpeg().input('./videos/placeholder-video.mp4')
  .setStartTime('00:00:10')
  .setDuration(2)
  .output('./videos/test2.mp4')
  
  const files = await Promise.all([ffmpegPromise(file1), ffmpegPromise(file2)])
  console.log(files) // ['finished!', 'finished!']

  ffmpeg()
    .mergeAdd('./videos/test1.mp4')
    .mergeAdd('./videos/test2.mp4')
    .mergeToFile('./videos/mergedFile.mp4')
    .on('end', () => {
       fs.unlink('./videos/test1.mp4', err => {
         if (err) console.error(err)
       })
       fs.unlink('./videos/test2.mp4', err => {
         if (err) console.error(err)
       })
     })     
})()
```

**File1** instantiates ffmpeg. The code is not run until ffmpegPromise is called with the '**.run()**' command.  It starts at 3 seconds and takes 2 seconds of video. Then saves the 2 second video clip to file './videos/test1.mp4'.

**File2** does the same thing except it starts at 10 seconds and takes 2 seconds of video. Then saves the 2 second video clip to file './videos/test2.mp4'.

**ffmpegPromise** passes the ffmpeg instantiated function to a promise, so it can be awaited.

**Promise.all** calls both 'file1' and 'file2' at the same time, and returns 'finished!' when files are saved.

**ffpeg().mergeAdd()...mergeToFile(...)** takes both 2 second video clips and merges them into one file, './videos/mergedFile.mp4'.  When completed, the 'end' event is fired and fs.unlink will delete the test1 and test2 videos.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.